# VueJS | Problem with data displaying correctly (v-if, v-else) - external server

Tags: vuejs2

I have a question about data display. Here's a piece of code (component):

```
<th scope="col">Visiblity</th>
<td v-if="page.visible !== null && page.visible===1">Yes</td>
<td v-else>No</td>
```

As a result I receive Yes / No.
Everything works correctly on the local server (xampp), however, after placing the project on an external server, the condition does not work. Although I have a value of 1 everywhere in the database, it shows me a value of 0 everywhere.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Edit:
hmm
I made a simple project in Laravel + Vue
I have several elements in my design. For example, draggable, visible-draggable etc. Works, but in list.blade.php I have a table with data from the database. One column brings up visibility with two value options - 1 or 0. After the record is created and saved, everything is fine. In DB I have 0, 1 value, but Vue show all like a "No". I should have "Yes / No" values ​​in list.blade.php.

I will add that I didn't use npm run production before placing the project on the server, but all components work, only v-if, v-else not.

Comment: you need to provide us more information to help you

Comment: I see "page.visible===1", could it be that in production it's returning a String of 1, instead of Number, therefore failing ===? You could test by saying `v-if="page.visible !== null && parseInt(page.visible, 10) === 1"`